# Keycloak infinite sso/login loop after logged in another application

Tags: loops, gwt, oauth, single-sign-on, keycloak

I have a GWT application with a public and a private area which I want to connect to Keycloak 3.4

But one scenario is not working. If logging in to another application of the same realm and afterwards opening a new browser tab with http://localhost:8080/AppName/ the application opens with the public area. This is fine.
Afterwards I click on the login button in the application linking to http://localhost:8080/AppName/sso/login

Now the problem occurs, an infinite loop of the following two urls (with different state param) starts:

http://localhost:8280/auth/realms/realmName/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=AppName&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2FAppName%2Fsso%2Flogin&state=e7546fb4-dd04-4349-8b7d-2d84c6781d97&login=true&scope=openid

http://localhost:8080/AppName/sso/login#state=e7546fb4-dd04-4349-8b7d-2d84c6781d97&code=uss.AOpenWEowTeb8VPVnJ7c8ndCEE-a9N90WZdOOP1t448.19896787-621d-4a4f-ac99-a2f4fd108deb.04c20f46-b52c-42d3-8e99-447e1b8ee5f4

This happens locally, so there is no proxy. And it is independent of the browser.
In keycloak there is a session created for the *AppName* client, so the problem seems to be in the client code.

When calling the url http://localhost:8080/AppName/sso/login directly in the new tab without opening the application before with http://localhost:8080/AppName/, there is no problem and I am directly logged in.

As Keycloak adapter I am using this library in the application: https://github.com/realityforge/gwt-keycloak

I am working on that problem for days, would appreciate your help! Thanks in advance ...

Tim

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a browser (front-end) app and you are using authorisation code flow (`response_code=code`). That is not usual and secure for browser app. You should configure your library/app to use implicit flow (`response_code=id_token`).